# Python - Remove Rows Based Specific Values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, jupyter-notebook

I'm having some difficulty removing rows based on certain criteria. In this case, there is a row with column ID and Code. If a Code is 26 and that is the only row for an ID, then the entire existence of that ID should be removed.

In the below case, only ID 124 was removed. Even though ID 125 has Code 26, it has a NULL value. I have many more columns in my dataset, but these are the only two rows of concern.

Input

```
ID   Code  
111  2     
111  5     
111  23    
123  27
123  3
124  26  
125  8
125  26
126  26
126  NULL
```

Output

```
ID   Code  
111  2     
111  5     
111  23    
123  27
123  3
125  8
125  26
126  26
126  NULL
```

Comment: Is possible to have the same ID and Code 26 in 2 or more rows? What happens in that case?

Comment: If the same ID and same Code 26 exists only, then the ID should be removed - great question! In the above case for ID 126, we had a NULL so we keep. But if that NULL was 26, then ID 126 gets removed.

Comment: please add one case in data where ID repeats with Code = 26 :)

Comment: Seems I have a few answers, I think we are good here! Thank you though sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a boolean index version:

```
df = df[df['ID'].duplicated(keep=False) | (df['Code'] != 26)]
```

Keep rows where the ID is duplicated OR where the code is not equal to 26 (single IDs with the code 26 are removed).  Result:

```
    ID  Code
0  111   2.0
1  111   5.0
2  111  23.0
3  123  27.0
4  123   3.0
6  125   8.0
7  125  26.0
8  126  26.0
9  126   NaN
```

Comment: I tried this multiple times, but the rows still appear in my dataset. In my master file, I have numerous more rows. That shouldn't effect anything, right? Should I format my csv file in a particular manner? Or should I ensure my ID column is formatted in some way?

Comment: So my ID column is INT64 while my Code column is Object. Most of the columns are objects while only a handful are INT64. Hopefully this can help - and thank you! @Tom

Comment: @Logan This may be hard to chase down without seeing all the data.  You're correct that the number of rows shouldn't matter.  Nor should the CSV formatting, at least if everything is getting loaded into `pandas` and looks ok.  The `duplicated` part shouldn't depend on the datatype, but checking against `26` could be an issue (say if your `Code` variables were actually strings?

Comment: @Logan but all I can really say is that this does work in the context of this example.  I can send you the code to construct this dataframe (as I am using it) to ensure we are seeing the same thing.  And then you could try to check how your data differs from this example

Comment: That would be good. My column contains both characters and integers, so I wonder if that may be the problem...So I figured out the problem, once the datatype changed to a float64 for the Code column, it worked. Looks like I'll have to manually convert any characters to integers.

Comment: @Logan moving this and posting the code [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223730/python-remove-rows-based-specific-values)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df[df.groupby('ID')['Code'].transform(lambda x: (len(x) != 1) | (x != 26))]
```

Output:

```
    ID  Code
0  111   2.0
1  111   5.0
2  111  23.0
3  123  27.0
4  123   3.0
6  125   8.0
7  125  26.0
8  126  26.0
9  126   NaN
```

Comment: My ID column is INT64 and my Code column is an Object (it contains characters as well). Since that is the case, the code is not working. Any suggestions please?